MYSQL - INTO OUTFILE change permissions of generated file
Using MYSQL in docker env, I'm trying to export the results of my query into a file.
I've verified that the file is exported in the right folder considering --secure_file_priv option.
Here is how the query look like :
SELECT * FROM my_table INTO OUTFILE '/usr/shared/csvfiles/myfile.csv' FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '\"'; 

So the file is exported in the desired place but i would like to set the persmission to 777.
At the moment, here is the result of ls -la myfile.csv inside of the mysql container.
bash-4.4# ls -la myfile.csv 
-rw-r----- 1 mysql mysql 13485 Jul  3 09:02 myfile.csv

I've tried to set the UMASK and UMASK_DIR  from Mysql ENV Variables doc but nothing changed even after mounting mysql in another volume to ensure previous configuration don't conflict with thoose changes.
Here are env vars of mysql container :
bash-4.4# env 
HOSTNAME=ef96a55bdf3a
UMASK_DIR=0777
MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD_FILE=/run/secrets/mysql_root_password
PWD=/usr/shared/csvfiles
HOME=/root
MYSQL_MAJOR=innovation
GOSU_VERSION=1.16
MYSQL_VERSION=8.3.0-1.el8
TERM=xterm
UMASK=0777
SHLVL=1
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
MYSQL_SHELL_VERSION=8.3.0-1.el8
_=/usr/bin/env
OLDPWD=/usr/shared

In case you need to know why i have to change default persmissions : another container running my app is trying to move the exported file into another location for archiving purpose.
I've mounted a common volume between both container to ensure the file is ready to be moved.
Any Idea on how to define outputed file permissions with mysql ?

Do you mean you want the permissions to be 0644; the file should be world-readable?  Can you just chmod the file?  Can you run this entire workflow within a single container, rather than trying to share files between containers?

Just the fact to be able to change output file permission would be great.
I can manually chmod the file but it require to be logged on mysql container, and that's actually not what i want to do.
The application asking mysql to export query results into a file is a php webapp used by my users and the archiving workflow is a routine handled by the app.
The moving part would'nt be an issue as soon as the right permissions are applied to the output file.

Do you need a separate container at all for this; can you directly execute this SQL query using your application's existing database connection, writing into the application container's filesystem?

Sure, but the php performances will be so bad compare to "into outfile" mysql statement..

select into outfile documentation says that umask is set. There is no indication that the two environmentl variables you mentioned would have any effect on the output file.

You're right in the note section they say that umask is set to 0640, wich is causing me trouble as long as we can't edit this value even with the env variable
